# jquery mobile external panel does not open properly

Tags: jquery-mobile, panel

I am trying to get a jquery mobile panel working.  Currently, when the panel opens it slides all the way covering my page instead of just part way.  I'm thinking it has to be something to do with initialization of the panel.

Any ideas?

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fatfantasma/0eck24uo/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="panel_home" data-role="panel"  data-position="right" data-display="slide" data-theme="a">
<ul  data-role="listview">
    <li>Panel Button 1</li>
    <li>Panel Button 2</li>
    <li>Panel Button 3</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page_home">

<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" >
    <a  href="#panel_home" > <img border="0"
           src="http://cdn-img.easyicon.net/png/11464/1146409.gif"
           width="30" height="30">
    </a>
</div>


<div data-role="content" >
    <h2>Page Content</h2>
</div>


<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <h2>Footer Content</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).one('mobileinit', function () {
   $("[data-role=panel]").panel().enhanceWithin();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External panels should be initialized on Jquery's document.ready:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("[data-role=panel]").panel().enhanceWithin();
});
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/0eck24uo/3/)**

Comment: Thanks. I thought I tried that but it turns out that I had several issues going.